# Changing Position of Title in Title Bar WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We are developing a WPF project and im stuck on how to change the position of the title in the title bar of the window. I need to put the title in the middle just like in windows 8. I dont want to change the look and feel of the whole window, just the position of the title.

Ive read that the title bar is on the non-client area and i dnt have an idea how to change it.

Thanks

Comment: This wilk could help? http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/

Comment: i came across this site too but as much as possible, we dont download additional frameworks/tools to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find one example of what you want to do in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144659/how-to-develop-a-custom-window-which-will-have-all-the-properties-of-general-win).

You need to create your own custom window style.  Usually the titlebar ends up being a  with column definitions, and the title ends up centered in the middle column.

Try to stay away from solutions that use transparency (Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="False" is best).

Comment: im stuck trying to figure out which control here is for the title

Comment: @Gpoy Gwapo look for <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Title" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />